# Sequence of 1-1 analytic functions on compact set

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of analytic functions defined on some open connected subset of the complex plane. Assume that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of $G$ and $a \in G$. Furthermore suppose the $f_n$ are $1-1$ and that $f'(a)> 0$. Prove then that $f$ is $1-1$ and that $f_n' \neq 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

My thoughts and attempt:

Let us suppose towards a contradiction that as $n \rightarrow \infty$ we get

$$f_n'=0$$

then since $G$ is connected we can conclude that the $f_n$ are constant (on $G$, that is). But this breaks the injectivity of the $f_n$. Would an argument like this suffice for the nonzero portion? To show $f$ is injective, should I also do it by contradiction? Assume $f$ is not injective. Then there exists $z_1 \neq z_2$ such that $f(z_1)=f(z_2)$? Then use the uniform continuity to say $f$ attains its max and min but I don't see how to use this. However we know then that the $f_n$ take on distinct values for $z_1,z_2$ since they injective. Then this would break uniform continuity?

Comment: this is (a form of) Hurwitz theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: The title of your question says "compact set" and in the body the hypothesis is "open connected set". Which is it?

Comment: @jjagmath edited sry

Comment: @Conrad thanks!